# Node.js & Express: Serving text files in parts

Tags: javascript, node.js, text

I have a webserver with node.js and express. When I serve a text file that is big, it takes a lot of time to load into the browser. Imagine a 34 MB text file being served to the client, he would have to download the 34 MB only to check for something in the log file.

Is there something I could do about it? Serve it in parts perhaps? Like: Part 1/10 - Part 10/10

Comment: It may be worth considering (if viable) ways to either parse out such a file serverside and only push out relevant content, or store it in some sort of database (parsed out) that would allow you to store it outside of memory but make it easy to query.

Comment: Have you looked at socket.io or ajax? You could load more data as the user scrolls down the page. If this is what you are looking for I can give some examples and sites to look at.

Answer (score 1):

To serve a file partial, you could take a byte range, and read that range with the filesystem function [`fs.createReadStream()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options). For example, if you wanted one tenth of a file, you could measure its size, and calculate the byte range.

```
app.get('/log', function(req, res) {
  fs.stat('log.txt', function(err, stats) {
    var end = Math.ceil(stats.size / 10);
    var stream = fs.createReadStream('log.txt', {start: 0, end: end});

    var log = new String();
    readable.on('data', function(chunk) {
      log += chunk;
    });

    readable.on('end', function() {
      res.send(log);
    });
  });
});
```

You could always modify the code to send from 10-20%, or to send the last 10% of the file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Node streams](http://maxogden.com/node-streams.html)? You can use them to send your data in small chunks, and offer feedback to show how much of it has been downloaded.

Comment: My only concern with this is the sentiment that "he would have to download the 34 MB only to check for something in the log file." Without knowing precisely what the issue is, it may still be worth finding a better way to filter data before sending it to the client. Using something like [hyperquest](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest) (via Browserify) with streams is definitely a good idea but maybe not the most significant pain point.